# How to solve 4 x 4 array with 16 unknown with Python (Update)

Tags: python, arrays, math

I need to solve a 2 by 2 array with 4 unknown

A B
C D

I know all horizontal sum A+B=11, C+D=7
I know all vertical sum   A+C=10, B+D=8
I know all diagonal sum   A+D=15, B+C=3

I then use Python to solve for A,B,C,D

```
import numpy as np

A = [[1, 1, 1, 1], 
     [1, 0, 0, 1], 
     [1, 0, 1, 0], 
     [0, 0, 1, 1]]
a = [18, 15, 10, 7]
answera = np.linalg.solve(A, a)
print(answera)
```

And the answer is [9. 2. 1. 6.] which is correct

Now I need to solve 4 by 4 array with 16 unknown

A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P

I know horizontal sum A+B+C+D=10, E+F+G+H=26, I+J+K+L=42, M+N+O+P=58
I know vertical sum A+E+I+M=28, B+F+J+N=32, C+G+K+O=36, D+H+L+P=40
I know diagonal sum M=13, I+N=23, E+J+O=30, A+F+K+P=34, B+G+L=21, C+H=11, D=4
The other diagonal sum A=1, B+E=7, C+F+I=18, D+G+J+M=34, H+K+N=33, L+O=27, P=16
Which mean I know the value of the 4 corners.

I tried the following code but did not work

```
C = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] 

c = [10, 26, 42, 58, 7, 21, 39, 33, 27, 11, 23, 35, 30, 23, 32, 136]
answerc = np.linalg.solve(C, c)
print(answerc)
```

The correct answer should be [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16.] but I got error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
answerc = np.linalg.solve(C, c)
r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
 raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Am I in the right direction? I will need to solve 5X5 with 25 unknown, 6X6 with 36 unknown and so on. Is there an easier way?
`-----------------------------------------------------------------------------`
**Following Mr. Rory Daulton solution, I can solve the above 1 to 16 4X4 array without problem, but when I use it in another array with negative number, it doesn't give answer as expected;**

The negative 4X4 array as follow

```
-20   -10    -5    0
-10   -20   -10   -5
-5      0   -10   -20
-10   -20   -10   -5
```

My python code as follow

```
import numpy as np
G = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # horizontal rows
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],  # vertical columns
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],  # forward diagonals
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # back diagonals
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    ]

g = [-35, -45, -35, -45,  # horizontal rows
     -45, -50, -35, -30,  # vertical columns
     -10, -25, -20, -55, -40, -10, 0,  # forward diagonals
     -20, -20, -30, -20, -35, -30, -5,  # back diagonals
    ]

answerg = np.linalg.lstsq(G, g, rcond=None)
print(answerg[0])
```

The output is not exactly the original array

```
[-2.00000000e+01 -1.31250000e+01 -1.87500000e+00  8.88178420e-15
 -6.87500000e+00 -2.00000000e+01 -1.00000000e+01 -8.12500000e+00
 -8.12500000e+00  2.13162821e-14 -1.00000000e+01 -1.68750000e+01
 -1.00000000e+01 -1.68750000e+01 -1.31250000e+01 -5.00000000e+00]
```

What should I try? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326015/singular-matrix-issue-with-numpy).

Comment: The determinant of your matrix is 0 therefore it cant be inverted you can check this out yourself with print(np.linalg.det(C))

Comment: I see 22 sums in text, but only 16 rows in the matrix.

Comment: It's a chore symbolically.  You should be using LU decomposition if you're doing it numerically.  It'll be necessary if you want a general solution.

Comment: I added an update to my answer to match the update to your question. Summary: to get one answer you need to add more information to the requirements of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:** There are infinitely many solutions to your problem. So this takes a more complex analysis of the equations.

**LONG ANSWER:** You have multiple problems with your code.

First, you make it easy to make mistakes, since the lines of your matrix do not correspond to the data that you present. Worse, you have no comments to explain things. This mis-match will probably cause errors. You have 22 pieces of data in your sums, so use them. You tried to combine some of the sums and ignore others (the four corners) but you did not do it properly and you ended up with a singular matrix.

Next, you use `linalg.solve`. In your problem you have more data items (22) than unknowns (16), so `solve` is inappropriate. [The numpy documentation for `solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) states

> a must be square and of full-rank, i.e., all rows (or, equivalently,
>   columns) must be linearly independent; if either is not true, use
>   [lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) for the least-squares best “solution” of the system/equation.

The matrix resulting from your data is not square, therefore the rows are not linearly independent, so you should use `lstsq` rather than `solve`. The `lstsq` routine gives more information than you need for your problem, so just print the first item in the resulting list.

Combining those ideas and adding a few comments gives this code:

```
import numpy as np

C = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # horizontal rows
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],  # vertical columns
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],  # forward diagonals
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # back diagonals
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    ]

c = [10, 26, 42, 58,  # horizontal rows
     28, 32, 36, 40,  # vertical columns
     13, 23, 30, 34, 21, 11, 4,  # forward diagonals
     1, 7, 18, 34, 33, 27, 16,  # back diagonals
    ]

answerc = np.linalg.lstsq(C, c, rcond=None)
print(answerc[0])
```

The printout is what you want:

```
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16.]
```

---

However, to be honest, there is no guarantee that this is an answer--just that it is a "closest" answer. Also, if it is an answer, there may be other answers. And, in fact, further analysis shows that there are other answers that satisfy all your conditions.

The `sympy` module can generate a row reduced echelon form of the matrix, which can be used to do more in-depth analysis of all the answers. However, the constants are then to be part of the matrix, rather than used as a separate array. Here is code for sympy to attempt to solve your problem:

```
import sympy

C = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10],  # horizontal rows
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26], 
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 58],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 28],  # vertical columns
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 32],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 36],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 40],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 13],  # forward diagonals
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 23],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 30],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 34],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  4],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1],  # back diagonals
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  7],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 34],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 33],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 27],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 16],
    ]

print(sympy.Matrix(C).rref())
```

The printout is

```
(Matrix([
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -13],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 0,  18],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   4],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 0,  20],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   6],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   7],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0,  -7],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0,  -6],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,  10],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,  11],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,  1, 0,  27],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 0,  13],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,  1, 0,  29],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 1,  16],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,   0]]), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15))
```

If you know how to analyze this you will see that there are *infinitely many* answers to your problem. If you set the number in the 15th cell to `15+x` then the above matrix shows that the answer to all your restrictions is

```
 1     2+x   3-x   4
 5-x   6     7     8+x
 9+x  10    11    12-x
13    14-x  15+x  16
```

The `solve` function of numpy only works if there is just one solution, so even if you had adjusted your matrix differently it would not have worked for you.

---

**ANSWER TO YOUR UPDATE:**

It seems that you missed the point of my answer. Your 4x4 problem has infinitely many answers, so there is no procedure that can choose the particular answer that  you have in mind. The `np.linalg.lstsq` routine can find one of the answers to your problem but probably will not find your desired answer. You should consider it to be a coincidence that using that routine in your first problem gave your desired answer--that will probably not work in other problems.

It is a little hard to interpret the given answer to your new problem, since the scientific notation is hard to read. But all those matrix values are exact, and here they are as rational numbers in a particular format that should be obvious:

```
-20          -10-(3+1/8)  - 5+(3+1/8)    0
-10+(3+1/8)  -20          -10          - 5-(3+1/8)
- 5-(3+1/8)    0          -10          -20+(3+1/8)
-10          -20+(3+1/8)  -10-(3+1/8)  - 5
```

You see that the numpy's answer is the one that you expected, with the value `3+1/8` added to or subtracted from half the array values. This makes `x=3+1/8` in the general answer that I gave you for your first problem.

This is as good as you can expect. Numpy gave you a correct answer--it has no idea how to choose the answer that you had in your head from the infinitely many correct answers to your problem. The only way to get just one answer is to change your problem--perhaps state the value in the first row and second column, or the sum of the first and third values in any one of the rows, or something similar.

Comment: Thank you Sir Rory Daulton for your detail answer. It helps a lot.

Comment: I accepted the best answer but I don't have the reputation to upvote yet.

Comment: @SimonSimoon: I understand--that's why I said "if you have enough reputation" in my (now deleted) comment. You have done well--you asked a good question and responded well to an answer. I hope you continue on this site.

Comment: I tried the np.linalg.lstsq for the following 4X4 array