# Inverse of covariance matrix in time series

Tags: python, matlab, time-series, pca, covariance

I'm trying to convert a method based on the Mahalanobis distance which works on images to my code which has to process time series. This is the Matlab code, where the users pass an image as the input and then first reshape it and then calculate the mean, the covariance matrix and its inverse (He's using images size):

```
function out = rxd(X)

% X input size = (126, 150, 204)

sizes = size(X);

X = reshape(X, [sizes(1)*sizes(2), sizes(3)]);

% X input size = (18900, 204)

M = mean(X);
% M size = (1, 204)
C = cov(X);
% M size = (204, 204)
Q = inv(C);
% M size = (204, 204)
```

This is my code, where I implemented this first part in Python. I do not have an image but a time series, whose shape is (24230, 30), that's why I avoided the reshaping part:

```
import os
import numpy as np
X = np.load('dataset.npy')
# dataset shape: (24230, 30)
# 1. Calculate the mean of the matrix
M = np.mean(X, axis=0) # shape = (30,)
# 2. Calculate the Covariance matrix
C = np.cov(X) #shape = (24230, 24230)
# 3. Calculate the inverse of the Covariance matrix
Q = np.linalg.inv(C) #Error
```

If I try to run it I get the error:

> LinAlgError: Singular matrix

What could be the problem? I noticed that the only difference from the Matlab outputs is in the mean shape, but I don't understand if I'm wrong with my conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring everything about MATLAB, your covariance matrix `C` [can't be inverted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix); by definition this means the matrix `C` is ["singular"](https://www.toppr.com/guides/maths/matrices/what-is-singular-matrix/), hence the [`Singular Matrix` error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326015/singular-matrix-issue-with-numpy) (So it's not about the code, but the data).

If you wish to calculate the inverse of this matrix anyway, [the pseudo-inverse function `np.linalg.pinv`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) can do this; *but do be sure to understand why you are doing it.*